# Libgdx load list of songs cause NullPointerException

Tags: list, audio, libgdx

I'm creating a AudioManager that list for me all audio from my "sounds" directory and insert them into my HashMap, but my app crash and shows a NullPointerException.

This is what I'm doing:

```
FileHandle[] files = Gdx.files.internal(FOLDER).list();
for (FileHandle file : files) {
    // NullPointerException
    this.sounds.put(file.nameWithoutExtension(),Gdx.audio.newSound(file));
}
```

---

I'm testing with my old android 2.3.6. That's the erro on logcat:

```
02-24 20:59:30.742: E/AndroidRuntime(3676): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 10
02-24 20:59:30.742: E/AndroidRuntime(3676): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-24 20:59:30.742: E/AndroidRuntime(3676):     at com.climbup.system.AudioManager.<init>(AudioManager.java:40)
02-24 20:59:30.742: E/AndroidRuntime(3676):     at com.climbup.game.ClimbUp.create(ClimbUp.java:94)
02-24 20:59:30.742: E/AndroidRuntime(3676):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:241)
02-24 20:59:30.742: E/AndroidRuntime(3676):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1361)
02-24 20:59:30.742: E/AndroidRuntime(3676):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1123)
02-24 20:59:30.757: E/SensorManager(3676): unregisterListener:: all sensors,  listener = com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput$SensorListener@4052ff88
02-24 20:59:30.828: E/SensorManager(3676): unregisterListener:: all sensors,  listener = com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput$SensorListener@40531668
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The backtrace for your exception includes more details, please include the message and stack trace.  Please include the log from your app, if any.  (Is this on Android or on your desktop?)  To debug a NullPointerException it helps to know precisely which object is having a problem, so separating every deference onto a separate line will help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

Comment: Which line is line 40?  One of the "." dereferences on that line is dereferencing null.  You can narrow the problem down by figuring out which reference is null.  (E.g, `assert(Gdx != null)`, `assert(Gdx.audio != null)`, `assert(this.sounds != null)`, `assert(file != null)`, etc.)

Comment: The line 40 refers to "this.sounds.put(file.nameWithoutExtension(), Gdx.audio.newSound(file));". I tried to use asserts but didn't work.

Comment: The Sound is an interface. I'ts possible add an interface into a Hashmap?